# Como resolver el error que voy a mostrar en la descripción de este Post estoy teniendo al crear una base de datos mysql en wampp con un archivo sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, xampp

Como resolver el error que voy a mostrar en la descripción de este Post estoy teniendo al crear una base de datos mysql en wampp con un archivo sql?

El error que estoy teniendo al crear my base de datos mysql usando xampps y un archivo sql llamado event_admindb es el siguiente:

```
Error
Análisis estático:

Se encontraron 6 errores durante el análisis.

Caracter inesperado. (near "{" at position 177)
Caracter inesperado. (near "}" at position 401)
Se esperaba un corchete de apertura. (near "{" at position 177)
Se esperaba la definición de al menos una columna. (near " " at position 176)
Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "10" at position 190)
Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "NOT NULL" at position 194)
consulta SQL: Copiar

-- -- Base de datos: `event_admindb` -- -- -------------------------------------------------------- -- -- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `evento` -- CREATE TABLE `evento` { `id` int(10) NOT NULL, `descripcion` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, `fecha` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, `lugar` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, `objetivo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, `video_url` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL } ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '{
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fech...' en la linea 11
```

el codigo de mi base de datos que es el archivo llamado:" event_admindb.sql"; que está en el repositorio:
https://github.com/afjkrtrtr/porgram_juanfgabrielriveratamayoi.git

Answer (score 0):

cheque tu codigo de tu base, al parecer en create table lo tienes con {} y es con parentesis (),, igual en el insert into al final no tiene ; en vez, tiene una coma (debe cerrarse)

acabo decorregir la base , lo acabo de correr y me funciono , lo probe en workbench y en localhost/phpmyadmin y me jalo todo

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
-- version 5.1.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 23-10-2022 a las 22:52:56
-- Versión del servidor: 10.4.21-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 8.0.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
--
-- Base de datos: `event_admindb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `evento`
--

CREATE TABLE `evento` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lugar` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `objetivo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `video_url` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `evento`
--

INSERT INTO `evento` (`id`, `descripcion`, `fecha`, `lugar`, `objetivo`, `video_url`) VALUES
(1, 'Resumen de la Entrevista', '2021-02-01', ' 6270 S Carolina 162', 'Preguntas a hacer a los que se postulan al puesto del que hay vacantes para ver a quien contratar', 'https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=545A361126072FD2&resid=545A361126072FD2%218411&authkey=AA_412lehx8TTMc'),
(2, 'Fecha de la entrevista', '2021-02-01', '165 E 36th St # 1C', 'Mostrar cuando fue la entrevista', 'https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=545A361126072FD2&resid=545A361126072FD2%218412&authkey=AGc7DvKwQVrxvWU'),
(3, 'Lugar de la entrevista', '2021-02-01', '   6270 S Carolina 162', 'Donde se va hacer la entrevista', 'https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=545A361126072FD2&resid=545A361126072FD2%218413&authkey=ABGnDlyNvIuvAX8'),
(4, 'Entrevistado', '2021-02-01', ' 6270 S Carolina 162', 'A quién se le va ha hacer la entrevista ?', 'https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=545A361126072FD2&resid=545A361126072FD2%218422&authkey=AAYGBHcfNrhVm1A'),
(5, 'Entrevistador', '2021-02-01', '    6270 S Carolina 162', 'Quién va ha hacer la entrevista ?', 'https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=545A361126072FD2&resid=545A361126072FD2%218788&authkey=ANm_oxKPWH0gItY');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `usuario`
--


CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             


-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `evento`
--
ALTER TABLE `evento`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `usuario`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuario`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `evento`
--
ALTER TABLE `evento`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=11;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `usuario`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuario`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: ósea que el código que me mandaste ya esta corregido?

Comment: si, pruebalo si gustas ya modifique lo que decia tu error, y lo ejecute en workbench y en phpmyadmin para corroborar(obviamente creas la base de dato primero con cotejamiento utf8mb4 unicode y le das importar, o desde workbench seleccionas la base de datos y luego le das ejecutar todo y me cargo, si tienes algun otro error puedes mostrarlo